# hide p tags that have not rtl direction

Tags: jquery

i have multiple p tags in my page and several of them have dir attribute with value rtl and others doenst have rtl attribute
i want to hide p tags that have not dir attribute and tried this code but doesnt work

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("p:not([dir!=rtl])").hide();
    })
```

i tried this code too but it hides all p tags on page

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("p:not([dir])").hide();
    })
```

Comment: `jQuery("p[dir]:not([dir=rtl])").hide()`

Answer (score 2):

I also used the same code `jQuery("p:not([dir])").hide();` as you mentioned and it works

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p:not([dir])").hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p dir='rtl'>rtl1</p>
<p dir='rtl'>rtl2</p>
<p dir='rtl'>rtl3</p>
<p>no dir attribute</p>
<p>no dir attribute</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try both option to hide elements do not have dir attribute and also if you want to match it with value of attribute by following jQuery method:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p:not([dir=rtl])").hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p dir='rtl'>rtl1</p>
<p dir='rtl'>rtl2</p>
<p dir='rtl'>rtl3</p>
<p>no dir attribute</p>
<p>no dir attribute</p>
```

Comment: I have just extended the Example given by AKA. You can also match the value with attribute to be more specific towards element!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with one more way

```js
$('p').each(function(){
  if($(this).attr('dir') === 'rtl'){
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p dir='rtl'>rtl1</p>
<p dir='rtl'>rtl2</p>
<p dir='rtl'>rtl3</p>
<p>no dir attribute</p>
<p>no dir attribute</p>
<p dir='rtl'>rtl2</p>
```

Loop through each `p` tag using `jQuery` `each` method.

Hope this will help you.